# Elasticsearch- Fast Vector Highlightling

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch's highlighting feature in one of my projects. I am using fast vector highlighting(fvh) which is faster than plain type.  I wish to know the disadvantages of using fvh type in elasticsearch highlight.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only disadvantage of `fvh` highlighter is that index takes up more space than usual. This is because parameter [`term_vector`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/term-vector.html) is disabled for particular field by default, but `fvh` highlighter requires option `with_positions_offsets` - the most "expensive" among others for that parameter.